# How to aggregate checkbox values into one value to post form Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, post

Is there a way to post values as one parameter via form post?

I have a form that has several checkbox groups where users can select several options.

```
<form id="form" action="url" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="first" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="first" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="first" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="first" value="4">

<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="second" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="second" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="second" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="second" value="4">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button">
```

I also have written some Jquery that joins the values for each name and comma separates them so that the output looks like this and I see it via the console:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
        var arr=[];
        $('input:checked[name="option"]').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).val());
            });

            $('#first').val(arr.join(','));
            console.log('#first').val();
        });
```

Console.log output:

```
option: 1,2,3,4
```

However, when I submit the form the values are being passed separated like this (parsed version) and doesn't use the Jquery code I have written.

```
option: 1
option: 2
option: 3
option: 4
```

actual query string looks like this:

```
option=1&option=2&option=3&option=4
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that the parameter is being aggregated or grouped so that the end output looks like this

```
option=1,2,3,4&option2=1,2,3,4...
```

I am not sure why it doesn't use the Jquery written values

Comment: Where's your ajax? Also, you have multiple elements with the same ID. And instead of changing `$("#first").val()` you should be storing it in a variable

Comment: I am not using AJAX it has to go via POST.

Comment: When you submit the form, the page identified in the form's `action` property is loaded and every value stored in memory for this page goes away. Even if that wasn't the case, Javascript variables and form fields are two entirely unrelated things.

Comment: It sounds kinda like you're trying to process the form data before and after the form is submitted. Why do double the work? Why not combine the values on the page that receives the form data (the one identified by the `action` property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly, but if you want to combine the values of the checked boxes and not see them in the request data on the page that handles the form's `action`, I'd create two new `<input type="hidden"` fields. Then, when you handle the form's submission using jQuery, you can combine the values of the other fields as the value of the associated hidden fields. Finally, remove the fields you don't want to see on the processing page right before the form submission completes:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function() {
    var optionCount = 0;
    var optionValue = "";
    $("input[name=option]:checked").each(function() {
      if (optionCount > 0) optionValue += ",";
      optionValue += $(this).val();
      optionCount++;
    });

    $("#option").val(optionValue);

    var optionCount = 0;
    var optionValue = "";
    $("input[name=option2]:checked").each(function() {
      if (optionCount > 0) optionValue += ",";
      optionValue += $(this).val();
      optionCount++;
    });
    $("#option2").val(optionValue);

    $("input:checkbox").remove();
  });
  $("#received").html(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search));
});
```

## Example

- The form submission only works in the full page view: https://codepen.io/VAggrippino/full/XNBQEo/
- View the code in the editor view: https://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/XNBQEo/

### Note

- You can't have several fields with the same `id` as you did in your original example code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to achieve this, it would better to make the POST call through AJAX and send the option as parameter.

Add a hidden input to your form.

`<input type="hidden" id="checkedValues" value="">`

Change your js to this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     var arr=[];
     $('input:checked[name="option"]').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).val());
     });

     $('#checkedValues').val(arr.join(','));
     console.log($('#checkedValues').val());
});
```

Comment: The issue is that the current system is requiring to use their form post since the initial form was written to only accept one option otherwise the whole code will have to rewritten to accept the AJAX call hence I am trying to figure out a solution that will allow to pass the parameters as one versus separate.

Comment: Yes, I have. It solves only part of the issue for me. The answer by Vince seems to be what I need as it removes the checkbox data from the actual submission so it doesn't have multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `ajax POST` and submit your type of data to it. See the following snippet:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var arr = [];
  $('input:checked[name="option"]').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  });
  var myData = arr.join(',');
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'url',
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': {
      options: myData
    },
  });
  return false;
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1ecs44w/)

Comment: This is an option, however it will require to rewrite our current solution that was written to accept one option via radio box but then decided to allow multiple options so the form post, etc is already in place this is why I am looking to figure out a solution that will allow to aggregate the form post paramters as just one versus multiple when selected.